# need Star Trek quote for father-in-law gift

Tags: star-trek

I am getting married and want to get father of the bride & groom gifts.  My dad loves Star Wars and my fiancé’s dad love Star Trek.  I would like to get them engraved glasses, but having never seen Star Trek, I don’t know what to put on my father in law’s.  On my dad’s I want to put a graphic of Darth Vader and then below it, it would say “Liz, I am your father”.  Can anyone think of anything father or wedding related or some sort of pun that I could put on the Star Trek glass?

Comment: The stereotypical Star Trek quote is "Beam me up, Scotty" (though it was never said in precisely that manner in the series)

Comment: Please take a look at the [FAQ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq) when you have some time - this is what's known as a "list question" since there isn't a _single_ correct answer, and is off-topic on this site.

Comment: That said, I suggest looking for something between Spock and Sarek (Spock's father).

Comment: I suggest you give a reasonable answer to a question or two, get two upvotes (20 rep) and come join us in chat, where I'm sure you'll get plenty of ideas.

Comment: @Izkata, I apologize if I asked a question that is inappropriate for this site - I wasn't sure where/who to ask.  Do you have a suggestion of where I could post this question?

Comment: @Elizabeth as I mentioned, chat is the place for a question like this. Just get 20 rep on any SE site (except SO or MSO). You're already a quarter of the way there.

Comment: @Kevin, thank you for your suggestion, but I really don't know anything about this stuff, such as what an upvote is.  But I really appreciate you trying to help me find an answer to my question!

Comment: I'd suggest "live long and prosper," but if that's too obvious, how about an appropriate variant of "I'm a doctor, not a ...."

Comment: @Izkata The way you phrased your suggestion to check the FAQ was awesome! Much kinder and gentler than anything I've seen yet on this exchange. 1+

Comment: @Elizabeth the number of votes next to your question is from being upvoted. Chat is like our messaging tool for chatting to people on the site about tis kind of stuff. I hope you get the gifts!

Comment: @Elizabeth: Here's a direct link to [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).